# Applying conditions before executing variable nested loop for permutation

Tags: python, performance, permutation

I need to get the permutations in the following way: I have `N` slots, and this slots can be filled with variables reaching from `1 to D`. To get all possible permutations I wrote a loop that gives me every different possibility.  The loops look a little bit "strange" due to it being a nested loop that needs to be variable. This loop would take two days to complete (for my condition with N = 8, and D=25), however I only need the permutations where sum of the variables in the slots are equal to `"D"`.

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

N = 4 # actualy 8
D = 16  # actually 25

test = np.ones(shape=N)

for k in range(0,pow(D-1,N)):

    if sum(test) == D:
        print("this is a suiting fit!",test)

    # last one gets always changed
    if test[N-1]+1 < D:
        test[N-1] += 1
    else:
        test[N-1] = 1

        for idx in range(2,len(test)+1):

            if test[len(test) -idx] + 1 < D:
                test[len(test) - idx] += 1
                break
            else:
                test[len(test) - idx] = 1
```

Since the above loop might look a little bit confusing I enrolled it into nested loops

```
for i in range(0,D-1):
    for j in range(0,D-1):
        for k in range(0,D-1):
            for l in range(0,D-1):
                if k+1+l+1+j+1+i+1 == D:
                    print("this is a suting fit!",k+1,l+1,j+1,i+1)
```

I cannot get my head around how to make it either faster by simplification or by applying the condition before iterating over the permutations, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible I don't fully understand the question, but, if I do, this quite different approach solves the `N=8`, `D=25` instance in a few seconds.

```
>>> sum(1 for x in gensums(4, 16))
455
```

appears to match what your code returned, and

```
>>> sum(1 for x in gensums(8, 25))
346104
```

An example `x` from the last run:

```
[9, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7]
```

This uses recursion to apply constraints *during* the process of trying to extend a partial solution, so can cut off many fruitless paths early.

Caution:  for efficiency, the lists it yields are most often *the same* list object, so be sure to copy each result if you want to save results away for later use.

EDIT: replaced with a somewhat faster version, and perhaps a bit clearer.

EDIT: and one more refinement: adding the case for `nslots == 1` allows to assert that `remaining` and `nslots` are both non-zero at function entry.

```
def gensums(N, D):
    def inner(sofar, nslots, remaining):
        assert remaining and nslots
        # If only 1 slot left, it's forced.
        if nslots == 1:
            sofar.append(remaining)
            yield sofar
            sofar.pop()
            return
        # If num slots equal to remaining, they must all be 1.
        if nslots == remaining:
            yield sofar + [1] * remaining
            return
        # What can we add next?
        # What's left over must be enough to put at least 1 into
        # each slot, so must have:
        #     remaining - candidate >= nslots - 1, or
        #     candidate <= remaining - nslots + 1
        sofar.append(None)
        for candidate in range(1, remaining - nslots + 2):
            sofar[-1] = candidate
            yield from inner(sofar, nslots - 1,
                             remaining - candidate)
        sofar.pop()
    return inner([], N, D)
```

Comment: Thank you really much!

Comment: You're welcome :-) Note that I edited this to give a faster version, using some stronger constraints.

Answer (score 0):

you can use permutations and give the length.

```
from itertools import permutations
d = 16  
n = 4
for item in permutations(range(d), r=n):
    if sum(item) == d:
        print("this is a suiting fit!", item)
```

I think you may not need permutations

```
from itertools import product
d = 16  
n = 4
for item in product(range(d), repeat=n):
    if sum(item) == d:
        print("this is a suiting fit!", item)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but will this improve the perfomance?

Comment: @Kev1n91 it is a very large list. I think you may need multiprocessing to reduce the time.